# Is IIS dynamic IP restriction adequate to prevent denial of service attack?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ddos

I've implemented IIS dynamic IP restriction, I am concerned that it may not be enough. For example, if someone was to send many requests from a huge list of various proxy Ips they could in theory get through the the safety mechanism?

Is there anything else I should consider doing in IIS or .Net Mvc?

Answer (score 1):

For any still wondering, here is a MS Blog covering quite a bit - it is focused on Azure but many of the points are still applicable to IIS in a non-cloud environment. [security-guidelines-to-detect-and-prevent-dos-attacks-targeting-iisazure-web-role-paas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/12/30/security-guidelines-to-detect-and-prevent-dos-attacks-targeting-iisazure-web-role-paas/)